# Map gives different values when setting retrieved value to int vs Integer

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

I have a map

```
private final Map<Vehicle, Integer> nextStopsMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Vehicle, Integer>());
```

and I'm accessing it like this

```
synchronized (nextStopsMap) {
            Integer i = nextStopsMap.get(vehicle);
        }
```

but I keep jumping into null value in situations where I can see that it is present in the map.

When I'm using an `int` instead of `Integer` it seems to work fine, but then I'm losing the null info. 
[image]

As you can see in the picture, value retrieved as an `int` is ok both times, whereas `Integer` fails. I think this rules out a synchronization issue, but I might be wrong.

Anyway, I'm curious why this happens, is there an obvious mistake I'm making somewhere?

Comment: Its better to post the code instead of a picture.

Comment: Need to see the whole architecture. It could be that there's something wrong with the `vehicle` parameter itself (perhaps it is coming from another thread, although it beats me why it would behave differently in identical calls).

Comment: @Atri I did post the relevant code. The image comes from debugger

Comment: @SergeyTachenov You can assume that the map has the parameter - I checked it as well while debugging. 
Also the `contains` line returns true.; it can also be retrieved correctly when using `int`.

Comment: You can't really "assume" anything when talking about synchronization. It's either correct or not. If the `vehicle` parameter was not correctly passed in into the thread that calls `getNextStop`, then all kinds of things may happen. Although it's hard to imagine why _this_ kind of thing may happen because of that, it doesn't mean that it's impossible. Another possible reason is that the map's internal structure is somehow corrupted, but that's pretty unlikely because you immediately wrap it into a synchronizing wrapper.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Let's assume it's incorrect then. Every time I bind the result to a primitive it returns correct value. I also bind it to an `Integer`, but then it fails. If it were a synchronization issue, wouldn't it return an incorrect value for primitive as well?

Comment: The thing is, when there are synchronization issues, assumptions like "if ... then ... would ..." lose their meaning. You need to make sure everything is correct instead of trying to figure out what goes wrong and why. It's mostly like memory errors in C/C++ when you're trying to figure out why the program broke even though the reason is in a totally different place and could have happened months ago.

Comment: Out of curiosity, though, what happens if you rearrange those lines? Try to get an Integer first, and int second, for example.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Oh, I'm sorry, I thought I took a screenshot of `int` call surrounded by `Integer` calls. But the result was null as well.

Comment: Well, either way, we aren't going anywhere at this rate. If you really want to know what's going on, then you probably should use some lower-level debugger and engage into some serious hacking. Otherwise, if you need to just fix it, then start by inspecting the whole design and look for synchronization flaws, or possibly redesign the system in a way that is easier and safer to make concurrent, but that's easier said than done.